# Sum attribute from model that has associated models that match certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, sum, has-many

In a Ruby on Rails project, 4.0, I have a `Payments` model that `has_many` `Transactions` model.

If I have the following data

```
SELECT * FROM payments;
id | paid_amount
---+--------------
1  | 200
2  | 300
3  | 100
4  | 400
5  | 100
6  | 600
7  | 100
8  | 100
9  | 800

SELECT * FROM transactions;
id | payment_id  | type
---+-------------+------
1  | 2           | cash
2  | 3           | credit
3  | 1           | credit
4  | 4           | cash
5  | 1           | cash
6  | 6           | credit
7  | 1           | cash
8  | 1           | credit
9  | 8           | cash
```

Right now, I'm calculating the sum of an numeric attribute `paid_amount` from `Payments`, that has a transaction of certain type, as follows

```
> Payment.where(id: Transaction.where(type: 'cash').pluck(:payment_id)).sum(:paid_amount)
> 1000
> # The sum of paid_amount from payments with ids 1, 2, 4 and 8
```

But this doesn't work fast enough with many thousands of records so I tried to accomplish this with `includes` without any luck.

```
> Payment.includes(:transactions).where("transactions.type = 'cash'").sum(:paid_amount)
> 1200
> # paid_amount of payment with id 1 is considered two times because of transactions with id 5 and 7
```

Any thoughts on how should I calculate the number I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query:

```
Payment.where(id: Transaction.where(type: 'cash').pluck(:payment_id)).sum(:paid_amount)
```

is slow partly because `Transaction.where(type: 'cash').pluck(:payment_id)` is a query that returns an array and then you send that array back to the database with an `IN (big_list_of_integers)` in the SQL. A slight modification will use a subquery instead, just switch the `pluck` to `select`:

```
Payment.where(id: Transaction.where(type: 'cash').select(:payment_id)).sum(:paid_amount)
```

that will result in one query like:

```
select sum(payments.paid_amount)
from payments
where payments.id in (
  select payment_id
  from transactions
  where transactions.type = ...
)
```

being sent to the database. This should be quite a bit faster with large lists.

Answer (score -1):

Use `joins` with a `where` to return only the transactions that you want

[joins documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins)

`Payment.joins(:transactions).where(transactions: {type:'cash'}).sum(:paid_amount)`